# Is it true that $E[Y/X]>1$?

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X$ and $Y$ are IID positive random variables with positive variances.  Is it always true that $E[Y/X]>1$ and $E[X/Y]>1$?

Using Jensen's Inequality I arrived at $E[Y/X]=E[1/X]E[Y]\geq E[Y]/E[X]=1$.  Similarly for the second inequality, $E[X/Y]=E[X]E[1/Y]\geq E[X]/E[Y]=1.$

By my understanding of Jensen's inequality, these inequalities *should* be strict, since the function f(x)=1/x is not linear.  But what if $X$ and $Y$ are constant?  Would equality happen then?  Is this where the assumption of positive variance comes in?

Comment: The answer is [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form).

Comment: I see.  Then is it possible for a constant random variable to have positive variance?

Comment: Tell me. $ $ $ $

Comment: My intuition says no, but I have learned never to trust my intuition in probability and statistics.

Comment: (And I guess the same crazy principle applies to all of mathematics?) How do you define the variance?

Comment: $V[X]=E[(X-\mu)^2]$.  Ahhhh thank you.  Good to go back to the definition every now and then, I guess.